# `ps` showing much higher ram usage than `htop`

Tags: memory, ps, ram, htop

I usually monitor my server resource usage. I am using `htop` for monitoring.

When running `htop` the memory usage is **1.3G**, which is fine for me.

But I tried to view the memory used by each process. For this, I am using `ps` command. To view the memory used by MySQL, I am runing `ps aux | grep mysqld`.

It prints these lines:

```
root     13908  0.0  0.0 112660   972 pts/0    S+   11:12   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
mysql    17984  2.6  3.1 2845500 387676 ?      Ssl   2017 2974:34 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

So, it seems that MySQL uses **2845500** of memory, which means around **2.7G** of memory, which is much higher than (**1.3G**) the full system memory usage showed by `htop`.

Is that the number shown by ps, a number of bytes, instead of kilobytes?

PS: I am using CentOS 7, 64 bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2845500 is the amount of memory *allocated* by the process, not the amount it’s using. The latter is given by the next column: 387676. Both values are measured in kilobytes.

Comment: Oooh, thank you very much! I understand now.